# Django combine foreign keys in a single queryset

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model in a Django application that is being referenced by multiple other models as a ForeignKey.

What I am looking for is for a way to create a **single queryset** for all objects of this class that are being referenced as ForeignKey by the rest of the classes based on some criteria.

I am not even sure if this is possible, but I thought about asking anyway.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    pass


class Book(models.Model):
    year_published = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person)


class MusicAlbum(models.Model):
    year_published = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    producer = models.ForeignKey(Person)

recent_books = Book.objects.filter(year_published__gte=2018)
recent_music_albums = MusicAlbum.objects.filter(year_published__gte=2018)

# How can I create a **single** queryset of the Person objects that are being referenced as `author` in `recent_books` and as `producer` in `recent_music_albums`?
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Django in front of me at the moment, but what about something like:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    pass


class Book(models.Model):
    year_published = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='books')


class MusicAlbum(models.Model):
    year_published = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    producer = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='albums')

Person.objects.filter(books__year_published__gte=2018, albums__year_published__gte=2018)
```

Or, if you have to do those first two queries anyway,

```
Person.objects.filter(books__in=recent_books, albums__in=recent_music_albums)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have on `Person` model instances a [`RelatedManager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager) for `Book`s and `MusicAlbum`s.  Probably they will still have the default names `book_set` and `musicalbum_set` since you didn't override them.

You can use these to find the books/music albums associated with one person instance:

```
persons_books = person.book_set.all()
persons_musicalbums = person.musicalbum_set.all()
```

And similarly you can generate the relevant queryset from the model manager:

```
qs = Person.objects.exclude(book=None).exclude(musicalbum=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same can be achieved by this :

`person = Person.objects.latest('book__year_published', 'musicalbum__year_published')`

or 
`personList = Person.objects.all().order_by('-book__year_published', '-musicalbum__year_published')`