# Select 2 related fields at one query

Tags: django, django-models

For example, I have the following models:

```
class Transport(models.Model):
    pass

class Car(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(Transport, related_name='cars')

class Train(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(Transport, related_name='trains')
```

To fetch cars and trains separately I can do the following:

```
Transport.objects.first().cars.all()
Transport.objects.first().trains.all()
```

But how can I do it in one query?

Comment: you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49241246/django-combine-foreign-keys-in-a-single-queryset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefetch the related cars and trains:

`vehicle = Transport.objects.first().prefetch_related('cars', 'trains')`

Then you can access the related sets:

```
print(vehicle.cars_set.all())
print(vehicle.trains_set.all())
```

The main gotcha is that you may only access the related set via `.all()` (ie. no filtering, no `.first()` etc.), anything else would trigger a new query, leaving you worse off in terms of performance than without the prefetch.